# Internal reliability for ordinal scale using Spearman correlation matrix

Tags: ordinal-data, matrix, spearman-rho

I have a question about estimating the reliability (coefficient alpha) of a pilot scale  by assessing its internal consistency.  The pilot questionnaire generates ordinal data, 9 items each with 9 ordered catagories of response.  The data set has 183 complete readings of the pilot scale.

My question is: Is it legitimate to calcualte alpha using cronbach's formula from a correlation matrix consisting of the spearmans's rank order correlation coefficients between the 9 items?

Comment: What makes you treat your 9-level scale ordinal?